# How to access the email address associated with a GAE's default service account?

Tags: java, excel, google-app-engine, google-api

I'd like to give my java gae app access to a google excel sheet I own. I found that I'm able to do so by sharing my sheet with an email address associated with the service account.

This works for me locally since I am able to point to a specific service account by setting the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS env variable to point to the `creds.json` file I downloaded.

But when I deploy it to GAE, it throws errors, saying `Request had insufficient authentication scopes`.

In the docs, https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials, it says:

> If you are running in Google App Engine production, the built-in
>   service account associated with the application will be used.

My guess is that it might be using it's own service account, along with its own creds / email? Is it possible to access those creds, get the email, so I can share my sheet with it?

Comment: Do you mean the default credentials at:  https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/settings ?

Comment: @GAEfan no I mean the creds you get when you create a service account here https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials